# How to dynamically pass select query to a procedure/function and get the record count using ref cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
FUNCTION prc_check_src_dest_cnt (p_source        IN SYS_REFCURSOR)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
```

p_source -- how to find the count of this cursor which is dynamically changing query passed by user?

Comment: You can only count the rows in the cursor by consuming it, via a loop. How will this be used - are you *only* counting or will the cursor be used for something afterwards? Do you have to pass the ref cursor, or can you pass the query text? (And why are you returning a string?)

Comment: In a sufficiently recent version of Oracle, you could transform the `sys_refcursor` into a `dbms_sql` cursor handle, describe the structure of the cursor, fetch the data, and generate a count.  But the premise sounds rather odd-- why would you want a generic method that just executes an arbitrary query, fetches the data, and then spits out a count, throwing away all the data it just fetched?

Comment: @JustinCave Hello Justin, I can think of `data reconciliation` as a use for taking counts of different queries.

Comment: @Mahi007 - If that's what you wanted, it would make much more sense to pass in the name of the table and to construct the query in the function.  I'm not a huge fan of counts as data reconciliation.  If you were going to walk that path, though, just run a single statement that gets the count from all the tables in the schema/ all the tables that you're interested in rather than, presumably, calling a procedure a bunch of times in a loop where different tables will be counted at different times.

Comment: Agree with your suggestion Justin.

Answer (score 1):

If you can pass `SQL Query` text instead, you can try the below,as **Alex** pointed out in the comments

```
Create or replace function FUN_REF_COUNT(IN_SQL varchar2)
RETURN number
AS
    v_count number;
Begin
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from (' || IN_SQL || ' )'
    into v_count;

    return v_count;
end;
/
```

Calling Function:

```
select FUN_REF_COUNT('select * from all_tables') FUNCTION_OUTPUT 
from dual ;

--Output  
!----------!-----!
FUNCTION_OUTPUT 
    1697
```